# ActionLink helper passes param without param name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net MVC app created using VS2015.

In my razor view, I have the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText: "Detail",
                                     actionName: "Index",
                                     controllerName: "SupportNotificationDetail",
                                     routeValues: new { id = item.DetailFilename },
                                     htmlAttributes: null)
```

The definition for my controller method is as follows:

```
public class SupportNotificationDetailController : Controller
    {
        // GET: SupportNotificationDetail
        public ActionResult Index(string id)
```

I have made no changes to the default routing configuration.

My problem is, the action link is producing the following URL:

```
ESBAMPortal/SupportNotificationDetail/Index/%7B43794F0E-23AD-4A70-AF39-3364E93F5832%7D.html
```

For this, I get a 404 error. If I manually edit the url in the browser address bar so that the id parameter is named - then the correct page is loaded:

```
ESBAMPortal/SupportNotificationDetail/Index?id=%7B43794F0E-23AD-4A70-AF39-3364E93F5832%7D.html
```

If I can find an answer to either of the following then I will be able to sleep tonight:

Why does the url without the named id parameter give a 404?
**or**
How can I make the ActionLink helper give the required URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you request the url `yourSiteName/SupportNotificationDetail/Index/somefile.html`, The request will be handled by IIS because the request url is looking for a static content html file ( The request specifically has a file extension in it). So iis will try to serve it directly without the request going through the MVC request pipeline.

But when you request `yourSiteName/SupportNotificationDetail/Index?id=somefile.html`, somefile.html is a querystring value. So IIS won't directly serve the response. It will be send to the MVC pipeline and since the request matches the route definition registered with the route table, it will be forwarded to the Index action method with the parameter id and it's value.

The default MVC route definition has a request url pattern of `{controller}/{action}/{id}` where `id` is an optional parameter to the action method. For this reason, the helper method generates the link to match with the above mentioned pattern , hence you are getting the url without the `id` parameter in it.

You can change the parameter name from `Id` to something else and then the ActionLink helper method will generate the target url with explicit querystring parameter name.

```
public class SupportNotificationDetailController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string fildId)
    {
        return Content(fildId);
    }
}
```

and in the view,

```
@Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Index",  "SupportNotificationDetail",
                                      new { fildId = Model.DetailFilename }, null)
```